# How do I add a video background to my WordPress theme using CSS and HTML?

Tags: wordpress, video

I have a question which I think, or am hoping, is easy to answer. I just don’t know what I am missing… Basically, I am creating a WP theme myself and I want to add an image for one site as a background and a video for another side as a background. If I use my text editor (without WP) and use the following code for adding images / videos, it works perfectly fine. But when I copy & paste that same code into my WordPress files, the image or video will not show up. I googled a lot, but keep getting the same codes that I already have and that are not working for me in WP.

````
<video autoplay muted loop class="video">
    <source src="/videos/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="image">```
````

Is this an issue with the path I wrote under source? I did create an images and a videos folder in my themes folder. But this is not working. If anyone could explain me what I am missing, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Assuming you created the new folders `/images` and `/videos` in the same folder as your theme stylesheet is located (usually named `style.css`), you'll need to tell WordPress where the root of the URL should point to by using `<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>` in your template.

Image

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image.jpg" alt="image">
```

and Video

```
<video>
    <source src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/videos/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Give it a try but if the above doesn't work then it's possible your `/images` and `/videos` folders are in a different place.